# Mac monitor is displaying screen but I cannot navigate my cursor to it

Tags: display, vga-adapter

I'm using a VGA adapter to connect my Macbook Pro to an external monitor and I see the Macbook screen on my external display but I'm not able to move my cursor to it. It was working just fine a day ago, all of a sudden my cursor is not able to navigate there and I'm not able to drag any open windows to the screen either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that it was inverted. Instead of navigating to the monitor from the left side of the screen, I should have been going through the right side. My monitor was set up to the left of my computer so it was a bit disorienting so I changed it.

Answer (score 8):

Check that the virtual display arrangement in System Prefs > Display > Arrangement is the same as their physical placement.
You can only move your mouse across between the two at the side where they join.

[image]

You can drag & drop either of the virtual screens until they match your physical layout. When dragging, both the virtual & real screen will display a bright red border, so you know which you are working with.
The white menu bar can be dragged separately & should be placed [if it isn't already] on your main monitor.

Also note that if the screens are not the *same resolution* [size actually doesn't matter, only resolution, as displayed in that control panel] then you may have a smaller 'gap' where you can pass from one to the other, as in this picture...

[image]