# How to allow mouse pointer to move to smaller display?

Tags: display, mouse, resolution

I have two monitors connected to my Mac (running Mojave).

- A sits "left" and has resolution 1680x1050
- B sits "right" and has resolution 2560x1440

So, when I put my mouse in the "top" of B, and move it left ... it just slides "nicely" onto A. But: when I put the mouse on the bottom of B and move it left ... the mouse pointer will be stuck at the left border of B.
Of course: B's height is 1440, and A's height is 1050 ... so when the mouse pointer is at y=1300, well A only doesn't have that.

But for me, it would be perfectly fine if the mouse just showed up on the bottom of A.

My current workaround is to remember to first move the mouse up when I get stuck.

Is there a (built-in) setting that allows me to change this behavior?

Comment: Related - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/259813/mac-monitor-is-displaying-screen-but-i-cannot-navigate-my-cursor-to-it Basically, it's not possible. The OS has no idea how large the monitors are, only what their resolution is. To get from the smaller to the larger you must aim for the 'gap'. Also https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/188730/how-can-i-warp-the-border-between-two-different-sized-monitors-so-the-mouse-doe

Answer (score 1):

Don't think possible for the reasons Tetsujin noted above. In past my workaround for different sized monitors was to position them corner to corner - e.g. top left or top right. It was easier to remember (for me) that the mouse would only slide to the other screen if I put the pointer in the corner of the current screen. Also meant windows I slid to the edge of current monitor would not accidentally slide partway onto the other screen.